# javascript array slice functionality in javascript maps

Tags: javascript, typescript

In javascript arrays, we have one method called slice which returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array. Is it possible to do same in js maps. For example, I have one map in my application having following data in the form of key value pair.

```
let dataSet = new Map<number, string>();

{1, 'Andy'},
{2, 'Jack'}, 
{3, 'Smith'},
{4, 'Dave'},
...
{99, 'Sam'}
```

Is there any way to slice the map according to beginning index and ending index and return an copy of sliced map (or array) from the original map. I have idea about `map.forEach((value, key) => {})` but as I know, this will always start from zero and iterate over every index. Not efficient while working with large data set. I want one method something like

```
getSlicedDataFromMap(startIndex, endIndex){
   // Logic 
}

getSlicedDataFromMap(10, 20);

// returns {10, 'Carl'}, {11, 'Jerry'}, {12, 'Steve'}, ... , {20, 'Robert'}
```

Comment: I don't think so, because `Map`s aren't meant to be predictably numerically-indexed like that - they're not arrays. You'll have to iterate manually.

Comment: please add a valid data type.

Comment: The *keys* of the map can be anything, not only numbers and you wouldn't get them in a sensible order. Well, I think you might get them in insertion order but that's not necessarily the order you want. You'll have to extract, sort, then slice. EDIT: Unless you literally want *any* slice of a map. In that case, you'd still just iterate and extract entries at index `start` to `end`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance But what if I have large set of data maybe in thousands and I want only 10 records from the middle. Iterator will go through the starting index and there might be performance issue.

Comment: @MaksimsKitajevs it's a valid representation of a tuple.

Comment: Use `.get` on the indicies you want to get, and you won't start at the beginning, you'll be able to retrieve only the values you want.

Comment: @RishikeshDehariya sure, iterating a lot might be expensive but not THAT expensive, you're not going to be processing each data. Still, it's the only way to do it. Maps are not arrays and aren't supposed to be.

Comment: well `const map2 = new Map([...map1]);` will give u a shallow copy of `map1`, but I wouldn't say it's any better than manually iterating...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take the keys, a subset of them and build a new `Map`.

```
function getSlicedDataFromMap(startIndex, endIndex) {
    return Array
        .from(dataSet.keys()).slice(startIndex, endIndex)
        .reduce((m, k) => m.set(k, dataSet.get(k)), new Map)
}
```

Comment: will that preserve the order??

Comment: it take the insertation order from `dataSet`.

Comment: @philipp depends on what you define by "order". JS maps use insertion order so this will "preserve" it. Whether that's the order you want or not, is another matter.

Answer (score 1):

I really like @nina-scholz answer and I think it's rightly the accepted answer for this question.

I'd also like to provide something for those who arrive at this question looking for a way to slice their `Map` based on arbitrary keys, not just ordered sequences of integers.

This answer is a bit lengthy because I want to express the journey so here goes.

**What kind of interface would we like?**

Let's first define how we'd like to use our function:

```js
const result = between('one-string', 'another-string', themap);
```

That's seems quite nice. What about non-string keys? What about something like functions?

```
const randomFunction = () => 'I am very random';
const result = between('one-string', randomFunction, themap);
```

That would be nice I think.

**An implementation**

Let's build out an implementation of this interface taking into account some ideas we might have from functional programming.

How about if we had the ability to `fold` (`reduce`) a `Map`? That seems like something that would be useful here.

Let's implement `fold` (Your implementation may vary and be more performant. I'll write this one out in a way that I find pleasing):

```js
  const fold = (fn, identity, [head, ...tail]) => {
    const res = fn(identity, head);

    return !tail.length ? res : fold(fn, res, tail);
  };
```

This gives us the ability to walk through the values in our map recursively (you might implement an iterative version, and that's great!).

Ok, so we have our `fold` function and our plan is to use that to implement our `between` function. Let's get into that for a moment.

**between()**

Here's an implementation of `between` that makes use of our `fold` function from above. We keep walking over each of the key/value pairs until we find the starting match, and we keep adding items to the result until we find our ending match.

```js
const between = (start, end, data) => {
  const result = fold(
    (agg, [key, value]) =>
      !agg.taking && key !== start
        ? agg
        : {
            taking: key !== end,
            taken: [...agg.taken, [key, value]]
          },
    { taking: false, taken: [] },
    data
  );

  return new Map([...result.taken]);
};
```

Great! We've implemented a solution that matches the original API we defined above:

```js
const result = between('one-string', 'another-string', themap);
```

**One more thing for a bit of efficiency**

Since we opted to implement `fold` using a recursive algorithm, and our `between` makes use of our `fold`, we have a slight inefficiency in that our "loop" will keep going after we've found our final item, even though we won't add any further items to our result.

Is there a way we can shortcut the recursive journey? There is! and it works by introducing a new type

**Reduced**

`Reduced` is a new type that we can add into the mix that will allow us to shortcut our search, ending things once we've found the last item we want in our result.

Let's implement a simple `Reduced` type and add it into the mix for a bit of a performance boost.

```js
const reduced = x => ({ x, reduced: true });
```

There we go, that should do it. Now let's use it:

First we need to tell `fold` to account for the possibility that a value has been fully reduced, that is, that the value is of our new `Reduced` type:

```
const fold = (fn, identity, [head, ...tail]) => {
    const res = fn(identity, head);

    if (res.reduced) { // <--- We've added this 
      return res.x;
    }

    return !tail.length ? res : fold(fn, res, tail);
  };
```

Brilliant! Now we can return a `Reduced` value from within a fold and the `fold` function will respect it, exiting early.

Let's get our `between` function communicating this to `fold`:

```js
const between = start => end => data => {
    const result = fold(
      (agg, [key, value]) => {

       // v-- We've added a finished property and we return a Reduced type from fold
        if (agg.finished) { 
          return reduced(agg);
        }

        return !agg.taking && key !== start
          ? agg
          : {
              finished: key === end,
              taking: key !== end,
              taken: [...agg.taken, [key, value]]
            };
      },
      { finished: false, taking: false, taken: [] },
      data
    ).taken;

    return new Map([...result]);
  };
```

And there we have it. We can now grab values between any keys in a `Map` whether they're integers, strings, functions, or anything else.

Here's some examples as a codesandbox based on our final solution

https://codesandbox.io/s/xopkm9jlzq

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible, as stated at [Mozilla JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Description):

> **A Map object iterates its elements in insertion order** — a for...of loop returns an array of [key, value] for each iteration.

That said, if your data is in the form of arrays like:

```
const myMap = new Map([
  [1, 'one'],
  [2, 'two'],
  [3, 'three'],
]);
```

You could do something like:

```
function getSlicedDataFromMap(theMap, startIndex, endIndex) {
  const sliced = [];
  let i;
  for (i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
    sliced.push([ i, theMap.get(i) ]);
  }

  return sliced;
}

const result = getSlicedDataFromMap(myMap, 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on some previous answers, here some helper functions in TypeScript to `filter` and `slice` a `Map`, built in a more functional way:

```
// Map helper functions
function filterMap<K, V>(map: Map<K, V>, predicate: (item: [K, V], index: number) => boolean) {
    return createMapFrom(map, items => items.filter(predicate));
}

function sliceMap<K, V>(map: Map<K, V>, startIndex?: number, endIndex?: number) {
    return createMapFrom(map, items => items.slice(startIndex, endIndex));
}

function createMapFrom<K, V>(map: Map<K, V>, reducer: (items: [K, V][]) => [K, V][]) {
    return new Map(reducer(Array.from(map)));
}


// Usage examples
const letterMap = new Map(
    Array.from('abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz')
         .map((c, i) => [i + 1, c] as [number, string])); // Map(25) {1 => "a", 2 => "b", 3 => "c", 4 => "d", 5 => "e", …}

// Slicing
const twoFirstletterMap = sliceMap(letterMap, 0, 2); // Map(2) {1 => "a", 2 => "b"}

// Filtering
const vowels = 'aeiou';

const vowelMap     = filterMap(letterMap, x => vowels.includes(x[1]));  // Map(5) {1 => "a", 5 => "e", 9 => "i", 14 => "o", 20 => "u"}
const consonantMap = filterMap(letterMap, x => !vowels.includes(x[1])); // Map(20) {2 => "b", 3 => "c", 4 => "d", 6 => "f", 7 => "g", …}
```

Hoping to have one day a pipe `|>` operator in JavaScript for a more concise syntax for `createMapFrom`:

```
map
|> Array.from
|> reducer
|> Map.from
```